# SQL Max returns duplicates if values are equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a view that contains a document ID column and a date column as well as a dozen other columns that aren't relevant to this problem. There can be multiple rows with the same document ID, but the dates are usually different. This signifies that it's the same document, just a revision of it. The problem is if I have two rows where the document ID and the date are the same, I get both. I just want to get one. It doesn't matter which one, as long as I only get one.

The following has duplicates where the document ID and date are the same.

```
SELECT FSD.*
FROM vFSD FSD
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT InternalID, MAX(FileLastUploadedDate) AS FileLastUploadedDate
    FROM vFSD
    GROUP BY InternalID
    ) gFSD ON FSD.InternalID = gFSD.InternalID AND FSD.FileLastUploadedDate = gFSD.FileLastUploadedDate
```

I've also tried it with DISTINCT, but it didn't fix the problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FSD.*
FROM vFSD FSD
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT InternalID, MAX(FileLastUploadedDate) AS FileLastUploadedDate
    FROM vFSD
    GROUP BY InternalID
    ) gFSD ON FSD.InternalID = gFSD.InternalID AND FSD.FileLastUploadedDate = gFSD.FileLastUploadedDate
```

Comment: looks like the inner select will be the row you want, then you are joining to get more rows..

Comment: Note: The duplicate *must* be introduced from the JOIN with FSD (read, it must be duplicated *in* FSD) as the sub-selected *cannot* contain a duplicate Internal Id record due participation with in GROUP BY. (And the DISTINCT has absolutely no effect.)

Comment: @user2246674 (what a memorable name :) ``DISTINCT`` should fix the problem if only the duplicate rows were completely equal?

Comment: @mzedeler I believe that the better method to solve most cardinality issues is analyzing where the different multiplicity was introduced and fixing that - DISTINCT is a very large hammer that can hide other issues :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to only bring back one arbitrary row in the event that two are tied with the same  greatest `FileLastUploadedDate` for an `InternalID`

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InternalID 
                                       ORDER BY FileLastUploadedDate DESC) AS RN
         FROM   vFSD)
SELECT InternalID,
       FileLastUploadedDate
       /*Other desired columns*/ 
FROM   CTE
WHERE  RN = 1
```